# Separation of reputation and privilege

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges

I've read several of the posts here regarding transfer of reputation across sites, and I generally agree with them: reputation numbers and badges and such are subject-based and there's good reason to have them separate.

But there are a few currently reputation-based privileges that have no relevance to subject matter at all. For example, I have nearly 6000 rep on Stack Overflow, but on Poker I can't edit a post for grammar or vote to close a troll? That's silly.

So why not separate privilege from rep in these cases? Keep my Poker rep at 400 where it belongs, but recognize the fact that I've been in the community long enough to understand the software, the culture, the expectations, and such.

There's no reason for totally subject-irrelevant privileges to be tied to subject-based reputation. And this shouldn't be a too difficult software change to manage.

Comment: I half agree with you so am on the fence a bit (no vote either way ATM). Your specific example has merit, and I agree if you are trusted on one site for simple things like editing grammar, why not others. Perhaps you could spend more time thinking about this, and propose a list of more specific things which would work cross site, such as edits etc. As it stands, you question is vague and wanting "some" privileges cross-site, rather than just some we could perhaps agree with. It would be nice if the downvoters could leave some reasons why this won't work very well even for *some* privileges.

Answer (score 21):

No.

You have to earn the privileges on each site by showing that you know *something* about that site's topic and culture.

While I could probably perform many useful functions on Poker (say), why should the community trust me? I have no posts and reputation there so the community can't judge whether I know the first thing about the topic or not.

Things you can do:

- Suggest edits.
- Flag questions for closure.
- Flag posts as spam.

All of these are useful activities to do while you build your reputation and trust.

Comment: I agree in principle, but I note that you carefully avoided my specific examples. How is the ability to vote for closure in any way subject related?  It's related to the culture of stack exchange, not poker. It should still be rep-based, just not subject-based.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - it applies because there may be cases where something is so off topic even someone like me with no knowledge can see that.

Comment: I'm confused: that sentence agrees with me. What were you trying to say?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - Sorry. I misread your comment. What I meant was that most of the time voting for closure **is** subject related. However, there are times when it's not - but you can flag in those circumstances.

Comment: Fair enough, and probably true. Still, it seems like minor things like voting for closure or editing a post for grammar--even when they might be subject related--are not so drastic as to merit waiting for 3000 points on every new site. That also makes it hard for new sites to start...if no one has that rep yet, how can anyone edit posts or close posts to get the new site started off right?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - sites start with lower reputation thresholds. In private beta they're really low.

Comment: That's cool....

Comment: @ChrisF In relation to "question edits" *only*, why isn't this a good idea? Grammar is grammar, and specific subject or not, edits are not really site specific are they? I mean, I know nothing about C++ etc but can happily edit and improve a question about it.

Comment: @James - there is always the danger you might change the question. By restricting it to your on site reputation you have to show a degree of domain knowledge before being allowed to edit unchecked. It's not perfect, but it works (mostly).

Comment: Fair enough. Do you think a 10K user is any more dangerous being able to edit on any site, than a 2K user being able to edit on their own site? I don't think it is. If you throw in the mix of robo reviewers, bad decisions etc, I sincerely don't see the danger at all (again, ATM edit privs specifically)

Comment: @James - Yes. I have 10k on several sites, but probably shouldn't be allowed to edit unchecked on sites where I have only a few hundred rep.

Comment: A 2,000 rep Stack Overflow user who only participates in the `Excel` tag can make no-review edits to `C++` and `Fortran` questions... but not to the `Excel` tag on Super User. Privileges could be shared in a *much* smarter way than per-site reputation.

Comment: @pkamb unfortunately there's no guarantee that  tags with the same name on different sites refer to the same topic. Your example works, but there are others that don't. I've been hit with this myself so I know how frustrating it is. Even more so when you have moderator powers!

Comment: I'm not convinced that SE users do need to learn each individual site, and I don't believe that hypothesis has ever been tested. Shared privileges would probably work just fine and massively open up the available editors/improvements for non-SO sites.